Resolve circular dependancy when using a Singleton in C++
So I have a problem when using a singleton Game class and the Story class.
Game.hpp
#ifndef GAME_HPP
#define GAME_HPP

#include <memory>

class Phase; // Forward declaration

class Game
{
  private:
    static inline Game* instance_reference_{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<Phase> current_phase_;
    bool is_running_{true};

    explicit Game() {};
public:
    virtual ~Game();
    const static Game* getInstance();

and of course the getInstance() method is defined in a .cpp file.
Story.hpp
#ifndef PHASE_HPP
#define PHASE_HPP

class Game; // Forward declaration

class Phase
{
  protected:
    const Game* game_;
  public:
    explicit Phase() : game_{ Game::getInstance() } {};
    virtual ~Phase() = default;
    virtual void handlePhase() = 0;
};
#endif

And some other classes inherit from the Phase class. Also, currently there is no Phase.cpp file.
Right now I cannot compile because the Game::getInstance() is nowhere declared.
but when I swap to #include "Game.hpp"instead of the forward declaration, when I compile I get this error:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../include/c++/13.2.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:97:16: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'Phase'
   97 |         static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../include/c++/13.2.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:404:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::default_delete<Phase>::operator()' requested here
  404 |           get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
      |           ^
./Game.hpp:36:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::unique_ptr<Phase>::~unique_ptr' requested here
   36 |     explicit Game() {};
      |              ^
./Game.hpp:13:7: note: forward declaration of 'Phase'
   13 | class Phase; // Forward declaration
      |       ^


So all in all, when I implement it how it is usually done, I have problems calling Game::getInstance() in the Phase constructor, but when I try to resolve this, it still won't compile.

Step 1: don't use a singleton because it's horrible. Step 2: move function definitions out of the class body.

And three, if you must use a singleton, use a Meyers Singleton. They are damn near foolproof, including thread safe.

Why would a singleton declare virtual functions? If it is singleton, why do you waste a pointer per Phase instance on it? What's wrong with Scot Meyer singleton? If for any reason your doing PIMPL, the definition of destructor must be visible at declaration scope of unique_ptr instance, or a custom deleter class must be provided.

You really really should learn about unit testability and "dependency injection". Meyer's singleton is ok but any kind of singleton should never be your first design choice.

If you forward declare a class:
class Game; // Forward declaration

You can only use it in ways that don't require you to know anything about it. So in header files this basically means you can only declare pointers to it.
That means this is not going to work:
class Phase
{
  protected:
    const Game* game_;
  public:
    /// This will fail
    /// You don't know that Game has any members.
    /// So you can't call functions at this point.
    explicit Phase() : game_{ Game::getInstance() } {};
    virtual ~Phase() = default;
    virtual void handlePhase() = 0;
};

The solution is to change the header to
class Phase
{
  protected:
    const Game* game_;
  public:
    explicit Phase();
    virtual ~Phase() = default;
    virtual void handlePhase() = 0;
};

Then in the Phase.cpp file add:
#include "Phase.h"
#include "Game.h"

Phase::Phase() : game_{ Game::getInstance() } {};


So apparently there are a lot of bad code examples floating aroudn in the internet. Since I am currently a c++ beginer, I picked a wrong one. When using the mentioned Meyers singleton, it all gets easier and the problems were resolvable.

Firstly, your problem is simplified a little bit if you use Meyer's singleton (How is Meyers' implementation of a Singleton actually a Singleton):
// also ... why is this const?
static const Game& getInstance() {
    static Game instance;
    return instance;
}

You should also define Phase prior to defining getInstance.
You can either put getInstance into a .cpp file or define it inline in the same header; you definitely need a definition of Phase though.
Secondly, you should define constructor of Phase at a point where you can actually call getInstance(), such as in a .cpp file:
#include "Game.hpp"

Phase::Phase() : game_{ &Game::getInstance() } {}

However, it makes very little sense to store the result of getInstance when there is only one game.
You can always access the game through getInstance, so what is game_ for?
You can probably get rid of this member entirely.
